# For loop: how to print last element without blank space?

Tags: python, loops

I have a strange problem which I cant figure out for some time now.
I have 4 nested for loops and in the last one:

```
for a in range(1, 10):
 for b in range(1, 10):
    for c in range(1,10):
        for d in range(1, 10):
            if flag_c_d and flag_a_b and control_flag:
                print(f'{a}{b}{c}{d}',end=' ')
                counter += 1
                if counter == 4:
                    password = True
                    passcode += a*1000 +b*100 +c*10 + d
                if counter == 0 or counter <4:
                    password = False
  if password:
   print(f'Password: {passcode}')
  else:
   print(f'No!')
```

How can I remove the blank space the last time it prints, i.e the last time all flags are `True`?
And I have to note that I still haven't learned functions and lists.

Comment: Please include the entire code so we can better understand the question

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  We dont' know what you mean by "interval", and you didn't supply output to illustrate.  Your posted code doesn't run independently.

Comment: Sorry im new at this. Here's the code https://pastebin.com/sAXXef7D
The output is "1291 1342 1381 1471 ... Password: 1471"
And i need 'Password: 1471" to be on a new line. By interval i mean the blank space(end = " ")

Comment: @Prune The question is clear. The OP loops and prints but wants to avoid the last white space.

Comment: Ah ... so *that's* what the "interval" is; thanks.

Comment: @Tarik exactly.

Comment: We need to you edit critical information into the posting, not in a comment, not in an external link.  Also, remember to reduce the code to the minimum needed to illustrate the problem.

Comment: None of the flags change during the loop. What do you mean by "the last time all flags are true"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is a possible solution:

```
separator=''
for .......
    if flag_1 and flag_2 and flag_3 :
        print(f'{separator}{a}{b}{c}{d}',end='')
        separator=' '
```

You can also consider using `functools.reduce`

Comment: i thought about that but now it has blank space before the first print ..
Yeah but thats the thing,havent learned those yet,so i have to do it without

Comment: It has an empty string before, not a space. Look carefully.

Comment: On the first loop an empty string will prefix the output string, after which a space will come first.